# В приложении .NET Web API 2 недоступен файл index.html в папке Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Создал пустой проект ASP.NET Web Application. При создании, установил флажок Web API в "Add folders and core reference for:" в окне "New ASP.NET Project". Добавил нужные мне классы модели и контроллера в соответствующие папки. Затем создал папку View в проекте и в ней создал файл разметки страницы index.html. Проект собирается нормально, но при запуске выдаётся ошибка:

[image]

Вот файл index.html, находящийся в папке Views в проекте.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Справочник пользователей</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Добавить" />
        <input type="button" value="Удалить" />
        <input type="button" value="Сохранить" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Пользователи</h2>
        <table id="users" style="border: 1px solid black;"></table>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var uri = 'api/users';

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Послать запрос AJAX
            $.getJSON(uri)
                .done(function (data) {
                    // Если запрос успешно выполнился, то переменная data содержит список пользователей,
                    // каждый элемент которого представляет фамилию и инициалы пользователя.
                    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                        // Добавить элемент - информацию о пользователе.
                        $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#users'));
                    });
                });
        });

        // Функция, выполняющая выходное форматирование каждого элемента списка
        function formatItem(item) {
            return item.Name;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

А вот метод в контроллере, который читает данные из XML-файла.

```
/// <summary>
/// Возвращает список пользователей, применяя GET api/users
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Список пользователей</returns>
public IEnumerable<User> Get()
{
    // Список пользователей, информация о которых находится в файле Users.xml.
    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    // Получить содержимое XML-файла "Users.xml".
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "..\\..\\App_Data\\Users.xml");
    // Заполнить список пользователей:
    foreach (XElement elemUser in doc.Descendants("Users").Descendants("User"))
    {
        // Создать буфер для записи информации об очередном пользователя.
        User user = new User();
        // Получить его фамилию и инициалы.
        user.Name = elemUser.Element("Name").Value;
        // Получить его имя в системе.
        user.Login = elemUser.Element("Login").Value;
        // Получить пароль, по которому он заходит в систему.
        user.Password = elemUser.Element("Password").Value;
        // Получить все возможные роли (гидролог, и.т.п) пользователя,
        // в которых он может быть занят в производственном процессе:
        foreach (XElement elemRole in elemUser.Descendants())
        {
            // Создать буфер для записи информации об очередной возможной роли.
            Role role = new Role();
            // Получить наименование роли (администратор, гидролог, и.т.п)
            role.Name = elemRole.Attribute("name").Value;
            // Определить, задействован или нет пользователь в этой роли.
            bool f_Assigned;
            if (Boolean.TryParse(elemRole.Value, out f_Assigned))
                role.Assigned = f_Assigned;
            else
                role.Assigned = false;
            // Добавить роль в список вне зависимости, задействован ли
            // в ней пользователь или нет.
            user.Roles.Add(role);
        }
        // Добавить пользователя в список пользователей.
        users.Add(user);
    }

    // Вернуть список пользователей.
    return users;
}
```

А это - XML-файл, из которого выполняет чтение метод контроллера.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Users xmlns="">
  <User>
    <Name>Гарин П.П.</Name>
    <Login>Garin</Login>
    <Password>GoldMan_#1</Password>
    <Roles>
      <Administrator name="Администратор"></Administrator>
      <Hydrologist name="Гидролог"></Hydrologist>
      <Drillman name="Бурильщик"></Drillman>
    </Roles>
  </User>
</Users>
```

Получается, что сервер "не видит" файл index.html, находящийся в папке View, которую я создал в проекте. Что нужно сделать для её исправления?

Answer (score 1):

Прямой доступ к файлам в папке Views по умолчанию запрещен. Вот соответствующая секция в файле `Views/web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
    <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Views в ASP.NET MVC задуманы прежде всего как результат выполнения действий контоллера, а не как статические страницы. Они скорее всего будут ожидать данные (модель) для рендеринга, и отображать их напрямую нет смысла.

`HttpNotFoundHandler` введен там прежде всего для предотвращения доступа к таким View извне, без вызова контроллера - потому что в обычном ASP.NET MVC приложении такое обращение скорее всего закончится ошибкой из-за отсутствия модели.

Если у вас есть просто статический файл, который надо напрямую отдать клиенту - положите его в любую другую папку. Например, в `Content`.

Но скорее всего вы просто ошиблись, и обратились к View напрямую, вместо вызова соответствующего метода контроллера (который у вас вроде как есть).

Comment: Но ведь index.html в приложение ,NET Web API трактуется именно как view, поэтому я и создал для него папку Views в проекте и поместил его туда.

Comment: А мне нужно вызывать контроллер из jskript, находящегося на странице index.html?

Comment: прописывайте ссылку вида /ControllerName/Action (например, /Home/Index) - это роут по умолчанию в новых asp.net mvc проектах. Найдите любой туториал по asp.net mvc - это базовое действите, оно там будет. Или приведите в отдельном вопросе весь код, кроме самого вызова - вам подскажут.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, как это надо сделать именно в моём примере. Где её там надо прописать? С благодарностью за помощь.

Comment: @user3769902 я же вроде вполне ясно сформулировал - ваш файл - не View. Он не рендерится через контроллер. Переложите его в другую папку и все заработает.

Comment: Не помогает. Появляется ошибка: "Ошибка HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden 
Веб-сервер настроен таким образом, чтобы не формировать списка содержимого каталога."

Comment: Кстати ошибка HTTP 403.14-Forbidden появляется и в случае если папка с index.html назывется Views.

Comment: Что можно сделать?

Comment: Сейчас ошибка о невозможности нахождения ресурса ушла. Вместо неё появилась "Ошибка HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden" и на её появление не влияет имя папки, в которой находится index.html. Я даже пробовал вообще без папки - то же самое.

Comment: по какой ссылке у вас появляется 403.14? по ссылке вида /Content/index.html?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23658/discussion-between-user3769902-and-pashapash).