# Ошибка Ошибка HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden при запуске приложения .NET Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

При запуске приложения .NET Web API 2 возникает ошибка:

[image]

Когда пытаюсь просмотреть дополнительные сведения о ней то появляется окно:

[image]

При нажатии клавиши "Да" в окне появляется окно отладчика (как я понимаю) вёб-страницы:

[image]

Подскажите - что делать. Я только 08.05.2015 узнал о существовании .NET Web API. На всякий случай привожу исходники модели и контроллера и HTML-файл, содержащий разметку и java script. Вот исходник контроллера в сокращённом виде:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает список пользователей, применяя GET api/users
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Список пользователей</returns>
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        // Список пользователей, информация о которых находится в файле Users.xml.
        List<User> users = new List<User>();

        // Получить содержимое XML-файла "Users.xml".
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "..\\..\\App_Data\\Users.xml");
        // Заполнить список пользователей:
        foreach (XElement elemUser in doc.Descendants("Users").Descendants("User"))
        {
            // Создать буфер для записи информации об очередном пользователе.
            User user = new User();
            // Получить его фамилию и инициалы.
            user.Name = elemUser.Element("Name").Value;
            // Получить его имя в системе.
            user.Login = elemUser.Element("Login").Value;
            // Получить пароль, по которому он заходит в систему.
            user.Password = elemUser.Element("Password").Value;
            // Получить все возможные роли (гидролог, и.т.п) пользователя,
            // в которых он может быть занят в производственном процессе:
            foreach (XElement elemRole in elemUser.Descendants())
            {
                // Создать буфер для записи информации об очередной возможной роли.
                Role role = new Role();
                // Получить наименование роли (администратор, гидролог, и.т.п)
                role.Name = elemRole.Attribute("name").Value;
                // Определить, задействован или нет пользователь в этой роли.
                bool f_Assigned;
                if (Boolean.TryParse(elemRole.Value, out f_Assigned))
                    role.Assigned = f_Assigned;
                else
                    role.Assigned = false;
                // Добавить роль в список вне зависимости, задействован ли
                // в ней пользователь или нет.
                user.Roles.Add(role);
            }
            // Добавить пользователя в список пользователей.
            users.Add(user);
        }

        // Вернуть список пользователей.
        return users;
    }
}
```

Вот модель:

```
namespace UserDirectory.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Класс User является моделью пользователя. Предоставляет информацию о пользователе в системе.
    /// </summary>
    public class User
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Фамилия и инициалы пользователя
        /// </summary>
        public String Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Логин, под которым пользователь входит в систему.
        /// </summary>
        public String Login { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Пароль, под которым пользователь входит в систему.
        /// </summary>
        public String Password { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Роли пользователя в производственном процессе (администратор, бурильщик, и.т.д.)
        /// </summary>
        public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Создаёт экземпляр класса User.
        /// </summary>
        public User()
        {
            Roles = new List<Role>();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Класс Role предоставляет информацию о роли пользователя в производственном процессе.
    /// </summary>
    public class Role
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Наименование роли.
        /// </summary>
        public String Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Назначена или нет данная роль пользователю.
        /// true - назначена, false - нет.
        /// </summary>
        public Boolean Assigned { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Файл `index.html`, содержащий разметку и java script можно посмотреть по [В приложении .NET Web API 2 недоступен файл index.html в папке Views](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422995/%d0%92-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-net-web-api-2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-index-html-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-views). Этот файл помещён в папку `Views` в проекте. Сначала я создал эту папку, а затем, уже в ней, создал файл `index.html`. Почему у меня возникает Ошибка "HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden"? Что я делаю неправильно? Как её исправить? Ответьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа (Ctrl+K). P.S. Java S**c**ript.

Comment: Как исправить ошибку HTTP 403.14-Forbidden?

Comment: Она появляется безотносительно имени папки, в которой находится файл index.html, содержащий разметку и вызова java skript'а. Я даже помещал этот файл в корне проекта - всё равно ошибка HTTP 403.14 Forbidden появляется при запуске.

Comment: Установил страницу index.html в качестве начальной и ошибка исчезла.